# Finite sum with three binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I need to find a closed form expression, if there is one, of the following sum:

$$\sum_{j=0}^m{n+1-k\choose j}{k-1\choose m-j}{A+2-k+m-j\choose m-j+2}$$

where all parameters are integers, $~1\leq k\leq n,\quad0\leq m< n,~$ and $~2n<A.$

I've tried a lot of binomial identities, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), [Concrete Mathematics](https://books.google.ie/books/about/Concrete_Mathematics.html?id=pntQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), [A = B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), and the [Wolfram function site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/), without any real simplification.

I've also tried [Zeilberger's algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html), which does give me a second order recurrence with non-constant coefficients. Now if it was first order or with constant coefficients that would have given me the answer, but now I need to use [Petrovšek's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petkov%C5%A1ek%27s_algorithm) to solve the recurrence. This gets too hard by hand, and I can't get the only [numerical implementation](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~petkovsek/distrib.m) I've found working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mathematica say the sum is equal to "Binomial[-1 + k, m] Binomial[2 + A - k + m, 
  2 + m] HypergeometricPFQ[{-2 - m, -m, -1 + k - n}, {k - m, -2 - A + 
    k - m}, 1]"

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention this; if you ask me that is more complicated that the original though (I guess it implies a discussion of what a "closed form" is)

Comment: Since you cited various sources but not software, I added it just to be sure, but I was confident you already know that. Btw, I hardly know what hypergeometric functions are... apart that Mma likes them a lot.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm really looking for anything here! Yes it does, me not so much, hahaha