# Combinatorial problem: triple binomial product related to squared Laguerre polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, special-functions, mathematical-physics, laguerre-polynomials

**Context**

Hydrogenic wavefunctions [1] include a factor given by Laguerre polynomials [2].  These wavefunctions are often encountered in a first course in quantum mechanics. They also appear in subsequent courses in atomic physics.  These wavefunctions are also applicable to the study of two-electron atoms such as helium. In the course of my studies, I realized that I can not determine how to derive the identity below. I have checked that it is true using software, but I can not show it.

**Question**

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\ell\in\left\{\mathbb{N}\mid n>\ell\geq 0\right\}$, how can the following identity be proven:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2 \,n \left(n + \ell\right)!} {(n - \ell - 1)!} 
&= 
 \sum_{j=0}^{2\left[n - \ell - 1\right]} 
 \frac{(-1)^{j} \left(2\,\ell+2+j\right)! }{j!}
\sum_{k=0}^{n - \ell - 1 - \left|n - \ell - 1-j \right|   }
\\
&\qquad\qquad \times
{n  +  \ell   
\choose 
k -  \left[ j-n + \ell + 1 \right]\left[1-u(j - n + \ell + 1 )  \right]} 
\\
& \qquad\qquad\times
 {n  +  \ell   \choose j - k  - \left[j - n  + \ell + 1\right]\left[1 +u(j - n + \ell + 1)\right] }
\\
& \qquad\qquad\times
{j  \choose    k + ( j - n  + \ell + 1   )\,u(j - n + \ell + 1)    }
\end{align*}
Above, $u$ is the Heaviside-step function.

**My attempt**

I looked in CRC and I looked online trying to find a form similar to what I have here. On [4] I found Dixon's identity, which does include a product of three binomial coefficients. However, Dixon's identity does not meet my needs. This is so since in my problem there is a factor $(-1)^j$, which does not appear in Dixon's identity.  I have searched this site and found [5].   I found at least one identity that includes the product of two binomials (e.g., cf., [3]); however, I could not find any identities with the product of three binomials. I have looked on this site for products of three binomials. In [5], I find a question with three binomial coefficients whose problem statement includes several leads, which will be explored in due time. In [6], I also have found a question with a similar expression to mine and the question in [6] also includes a factor $(-1)^j$.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Multiplication_theorems

[3] [Proof of $\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{m}{j}\binom{n-m}{k-j}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ (Another form of the Chu–Vandermonde identity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409187/proof-of-sum-m-0n-binommj-binomn-mk-j-binomn1k1-another?rq=1)

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

[5] [Finite sum with three binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671448/finite-sum-with-three-binomial-coefficients)

[6] [sum of product of three binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306828/sum-of-product-of-three-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but just incase - I recently came across a similar form in my own problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510926/prove-an-identity-for-finite-sum-of-product-of-three-binomial-coefficients/4510956#4510956). I have not checked the indices, but perhaps its related.